# How to test the spring check_token endpoint

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, automated-tests, spring-security-oauth2

The API is using the spring built in /oauth/check_token endpoint to validate the user with the basic auth. I can't seem to come up with any other scenario other than passing the invalid credentials. 
Are there any other scenarios ?

Answer (score 5):

to check this endpoint, you should have a valid unexpired token. 
you need to pass client authentication in the Authorization header along with the access token. 
curl example:
curl -X POST \ 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/check_token?token=' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'authorization: Basic '

if the Client Auth and access token are valid you would get back the token details (in case of JWT, decoded token).

Comment: I guess if you have ".checkTokenAccess("permitAll())" on Authorization Server side, you can send the token only.